# How do I set the scroller to invisible in a mobile skin

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, skinning, flex-spark

... while still enabling it scroll?

I have a Spark List running in a mobile application. When I turn on horizontal scroll bars and then when I swipe as I use the application scroller bars fade in and then fade out. I would like them to always be invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your css file do this

```
s|List s|HScrollBar {
    skinClass: ClassReference("ScrollBarSkin");
    fixedThumbSize:true;
}
s|List s|VScrollBar {
    skinClass: ClassReference("ScrollBarSkin");
    fixedThumbSize:true;
}
```

create a class like this

```
package 
{
    import spark.components.HScrollBar;
    import spark.skins.mobile.HScrollBarSkin;

    public class ScrollBarSkin extends HScrollBarSkin
    {
        public function ScrollBarSkin()
        {
            super();
            alpha = 0.0;
            visible = false;
        }

    }
}
```

All your list scroll bar will be invisible, hope this will help

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but FYI there is a couple more examples of mobile Scroller visibility with explanations here: http://flexponential.com/2011/07/30/controlling-scroll-bar-visibility-in-a-mobile-scroller/